# Differential notation and chain rule question.

Tags: calculus

[image]

In the problem above, what is the difference between `dy/dx` and `d/dx`? Conceptually, how are they different. I know the former is the `\Delta y` with respect to `\Delta x` as x -> 0, but what is the latter?

And then my textbook does not use `d/dx` in this example. What gives?:

[image]

Here's another instance where they use the confusing `d/dx` notation:

[image]

Comment: Actually I think it is useful as an operator, i am talking about $\frac{d}{dx}$. Linearity , and other properties. But $\frac{d\text{(something)}}{dx}$ can be ragarded as ratio. Further reading: [wikipedia - differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)

Comment: What? Can you explain? How is that operator different from `dy/dx`?

Comment: Operator is developed for ease mainly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d/dx Notation Explanation please?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672612/d-dx-notation-explanation-please)

Answer (score 2):

See it this way: We are talking here about function terms in a real variable $x$, like $3x^2-7x+5$, $e^{\sin x}$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, etc.

The typographical picture ${d\over dx}$ denotes an operator that can be applied to such terms. It takes the derivative with respect to $x$ of such a term, according to the rules learnt in calculus 101.

Now in your context $y$ is an abbreviation for some more complicated term in the variable $x$. The author then does not write ${d\over dx}y$ in order to get the derivative, but he writes ${dy\over dx}$. That's all.

You have to be aware than in our "working analysis" we all are somewhat sloppy with the notations of variables, functions, operators, etc. The same $y$ can be an independent coordinate variable, a dependent variable tied to an independent variable $x$ via $y=f(x)$, or denote some given or unknown function taking values on the $y$-axis, and on and on.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the *result* of applying the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $y$.  $e^{sin(x)}cos(x)$ is the result of applying the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $e^{sin(x)}$.  If $y=e^{sin(x)}$, then, if you apply the same operator to both sides, you wind up with:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y) = \frac{d}{dx}(e^{sin(x)})$$

This then simplifies to:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{sin(x)}cos(x)$$

Personally, I prefer separating $d()$ from $\frac{}{dx}$ as two separate operations, but nobody that I can find teaches it that way.

In the second example, $\theta$ is simply in the place of $x$, because $\theta$ is the variable the derivative is being taken with respect to.  It's exactly the same operation.