what is d/dx and what does it mean and what it can be useful?
I know this is very simple to anyone who did this before but as a person who's bad at math whos learning this I just thought is there a explanation on what exactltly does or what it can be used for. I thought maybe understanding what this whole thing is can help me. I know its derivative and it represents the rate of change but if examples can be given it could help allot. Thanks in advance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/why-are-derivatives-specified-as-fracddx

Derivative are possibly the single most useful concept in all of Mathematics. A hundred books couldn't cover all its uses. Just to start: velocity is the derivative of distance with respect to time, and acceleration is the derivative of velocity.

You might also be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25054/different-ways-of-thinking-about-the-derivative
